# trying to install nodejs with - apt install nodejs

Tags: apt, nodejs

Here is what it gives me:

```
root@tal-HP-Notebook:~# apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-176-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-176-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-176-generic but it is not going to be installed
 nodejs : Depends: libuv1 (>= 1.6.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Do you know what to do?

---

When i try apt-get -f install, it gives me the following:

```
root@tal-HP-Notebook:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 252 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6,937 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,238 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic amd64 4.4.0-176.206 [6,937 kB]
Fetched 6,937 kB in 7s (892 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 590241 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic_4.4.0-176.206_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic (4.4.0-176.206) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic_4.4.0-176.206_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-176-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-176-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-176-generic_4.4.0-176.206_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

I think the whole problem is that i don't have enough disk space on the boot partition (it only has 500mb and is currently full).

I tried a few things, including trying to purge/erase some older kernel versions, but to no avail.

For some reason when i start the computer i have to press <kbd>del</kbd> in order to boot the computer with some older kernel version, it got messed up (and i didn't touch the version which was active).

I hope you'll be able to help me..

Comment: It tells you: "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these". Did you do that? If yes: what happened? If no: Try it please.

Comment: when i try apt-get -f install - it gives me the following: (i'll post it as an answer to my question...)